# An alternative definition for symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

The usual definition for symmetric positive definite matrices is to say that a symmetric matrix  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is positive definite if for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \left\{0 \right\}  $ it holds that
$$ x^T Ax > 0. $$

However, I have now encountered another definition which is the following: A symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite if there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^N $ it holds that
$$ x^T Ax \ge C x^T x. $$

It is unclear to me, how these are equivalent. Of course, if the latter condition is satisfied, then the first one is satisfied. But what about the other direction? I guess that
$$ C = \inf \left\{ \frac{x^T Ax}{x^T x} : x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \left\{0 \right\} \right\}, $$
but I am not sure how to show that $C > 0$.

Comment: One possibility is find the minimum of $x^TAx$ under the constraint $x^Tx=1$ via langrange multiplier. You then find that the minimum is attained by an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: the infimum over all $x$ not zero can be rewritten as a minimum on the unit norm vectors, that is non-zero, since the minimum is always attained for some non zero vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ${\bf x^TAx} \ge { a \bf x^Tx}$ for some $a>0$ not dependent on $\bf x$ if $\bf A$ is positive definite matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030774/is-bf-xtax-ge-a-bf-xtx-for-some-a0-not-dependent-on-bf-x-if)

Comment: $C$ is merely $A$'s smallest eigenvalue (think about [diagonalization of real symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566681/how-to-prove-real-symmetric-matrix-is-diagonalizable-with-reference-request)).

Answer (score 6):

$\{x: \|x\|=1\}$ is a compact set. The positive continuous function $x^{T}Ax$ has a positive minimum value $C$ on the compact set. We now have $x^{T}Ax \geq C$ for $\|x\|=1$ and taking $x=\frac y {\|y\|}$ we get $y^{T}Ay \geq C y^{T}y$ for any $y\neq 0$ but the inequality trivially holds for $y=0$.

Comment: Just to add, for completeness, the case of $y=0$ is trivially true.